# What is the correct way to visualize potentials when the test charge is negative?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

[image: dipole]

I use this picture to visualize a dipole system.  The +ve charge is at a higher potential and -ve charge is at a lower potential. It is easy to explain to someone how a '+ve test charge' kept at midpoint would roll downhill towards the -ve charge.

But if I take a '-ve test charge', what is the best way to intuitively explain the result?

1. Should I invert the picture and take it as how the '-ve test charge' sees it?  In that case, the downhill would be towards +ve charge.  But this would put +ve charge at a lower potential.
2. Should I just take it that '-ve test charge' would always go from lower to higher potential?

**A quick context behind:**
I came across this question yesterday:  *Imagine you are moving a positive test charge along the line between two, fixed, identical point charges. Thinking of the electric potential, is the midpoint analogous to the top of a hill or the bottom of a valley? Does it make a difference if the charges are both positive or both negative? What if the test charge is negative?*

While the answer is pretty simple, I am finding it hard to fit it into an intuitive picture.

Comment: Depends on what you want to plot. If you plot the electric potential $V$, then it is independent of the sign of the test charge, and the negative charge is pushed towards higher electrical potential. But the potential energy of a particle with charge $q$ is $U=qV$, and by definition, $F=-\nabla U$, so a particle is always pushed towards the potential energy minumum.

Comment: Whatever force there is a positive test charge it will be in the the same magnitude and in an  opposite direction for a negative test charge of the same magnitude as that of the positive test charge..  Thus, negative charge "roll" uphill.